# mysql select query problem

Tags: php, mysql

i have a form that has a multiple select drop down. a user can select more than one options in the select. the name of the select is `array[]`; using php I call `implode(",",$array)`
in mysql db, it stores the field as a text in this format `"places"= "new york, toronto, london"` when i want to display these fields i explode the commas.

I am trying to run a report to display the places. here is my select:

`"select * from mytable where db.places .. userSelectedPlaces"`

how can i check toronto in lists of "places" that user selected? note "places" in the db might be either just "toronto" or it might be comma separated lists of places like "ny, toronto, london, paris, etc".

Comment: This could use some code formatting... http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I agree with Justin Ethier. But if you have to, look into the LOCATE function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_locate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is possible, you would be much better off using another table to hold the places that the user has selected. Call it `SelectedPlaces` with columns:

- `mytable_id` - To join back to the table in your query
- `place` - EG: "Toronto"

Then you can run a simple query to figure out if Toronto has been selected:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable m
 INNER JOIN SelectedPlaces sp ON sp.mytable_id = m.id
 WHERE sp.place = 'Toronto'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your database design is just wrong. Try reading about it more. Generally, in good design you should not have lists of values as one field in database and you should introduce new table for it.

But if you want to do it this way, you can use [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) function.

Comment: the reason why the design is like this is because, a person has been to several places, and we didn't want to store the places in other table. note i am using "places" in replace to my actual objective.

Comment: I see, but this table is denormalized, this is a sign that you have something wrong with your desing. According to database design principles you should introduce new table for storing places visited by each user. See Justin Ethier's answer, he described how this should look.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, this should work:

```
WHERE DB.PLACES LIKE '%TORONTO%'
```

but as other users said, its not a nice thing to have denormalized tables.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, your query needs to look something like this

```
SELECT *
  FROM mytable
 WHERE places LIKE( '%toronto%' )
```

But, be aware, that LIKE() is slow.

To indirectly answer your question, your database schema is all wrong.  That is not the right way to do a M:N (many-to-many) relationship.

Imagine instead you had this

```
mytable         place                    mytable_place            
+------------+  +----------+----------+  +------------+----------+ 
| mytable_id |  | place_id | name     |  | mytable_id | place_id | 
+------------+  +----------+----------+  +------------+----------+ 
| 1          |  | 1        | new york |  | 1          | 1        | 
| 2          |  | 2        | toronto  |  | 1          | 2        | 
| 3          |  | 3        | london   |  | 1          | 3        | 
+------------+  +----------+----------+  | 2          | 2        | 
                                         | 3          | 1        | 
                                         | 3          | 3        | 
                                         +------------+----------+
```

The table `mytable_places` is what's called a lookup table (or, xref/cross-reference table, or correlation table).  Its only job is to keep track of which `mytable` records have which `place` records, and vice versa.

From this example we can see that The 1st `mytable` record has **all 3** places, the 2nd has only **toronto**, and the 3rd has **new york** and **london**.

This opens you up too all sorts of queries that would be difficult, expensive, or impossible with your current design.

Want to know how many `mytable` records have toronto?  No problem

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM mytable_place x
  LEFT JOIN place p
    ON p.place_id = x.place_id
 WHERE p.name = 'toronto';
```

How about the number of `mytable` records per place, sorted?

```
SELECT p.name
     , COUNT(*) as `count`
  FROM mytable_place x
  LEFT JOIN place p
    ON p.place_id = x.place_id
 GROUP BY p.place_id
 ORDER BY `count` DESC, p.name ASC
```

And these are going to be *much* faster than any query using LIKE since they can use indexes on columns such as `place.name`.